# Replacing TabHost with ActionBar

Tags: java, android, tabs

I want to replace the TabHost and implement ActionBar but I'm facing an issue: the first line from the Main Activity ( `public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener{` ) is giving me an error: **Class "MainActivity" must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method "onTabSelected(Tab, FragmentTransaction)" in TabListener**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener{
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;    
    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    ActionBar actionbar;
    ViewPager viewpager;
    FragmentPageAdapter ft;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        ft = new FragmentPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        actionbar = getActionBar();
        viewpager.setAdapter(ft);
        actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText("Tab1").setTabListener(this));
        actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText("Tab2").setTabListener(this));
        actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText("Tab3").setTabListener(this));
        viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
                actionbar.setSelectedNavigationItem(arg0);
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

        });
```

FragmentPageAdapter.java

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class FragmentPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public FragmentPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (arg0) {
            case 0:
                return new Tab1();
            case 1:
                return new Tab2();
            case 2:
                return new Tab3();
            default:
                break;
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `ActionBar.TabListener` interface. To do so, create these functions in your activity:

```
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
// Called when a tab that is already selected is chosen again by the user.
}
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
   // Called when a tab enters the selected state.
}
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
   // Called when a tab exits the selected state.
}
```